# react-responsive Invalid-hook-call

Tags: react-native, media-queries, styled-components, react-native-web

I 'm trying to use react-responsive in a monorepos with styled-component and react-native-web.
I've a workspace like my ui lib and i define my component like that:

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import { theme } from '@components/theme';
import MediaQuery from 'react-responsive';

interface CardProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    tag: string;
}

const  Card = (props: CardProps) => {
    console.log("Card -> props", props)
    
    return (
        <Container>
            <MediaQuery minDeviceWidth={1000}>
                <Tag>'blablabla</Tag>
            </MediaQuery>
            <TagContainer>
                <Tag>{props.tag}</Tag>
            </TagContainer>
            <MainContent>{props.children}</MainContent>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

I define the style like that:

```
const Container = styled.View`
    display: flex;
    flexDirection: column;
    minWidth: ${theme.width.minCard};
    maxWidth: ${theme.width.maxCard};
    height: ${theme.height.card};
    boxShadow: 0 0 10px ${theme.colors.primaryGrey};
    border: 1px solid ${theme.colors.primaryYellow};
    borderRadius: ${theme.borderRadius.rectangular};
    marginBottom: ${theme.margins.medium};
`;

const TagContainer = styled.View`
    display: flex;
    flexDirection: row-reverse;
`;
```

I'm trying to use this component in my react-native app located in another workspace like this:

```
return (
            <View>
                <Specialist
                    key={psychologist.uuid}
                    img={psychologist.avatar.url}
                    name={psychologist.fullname}
                    job={psychologist.job_name}
                    description={psychologist.description}
                />
            </View>
        );
```

Each time, I find myself blocked by this error:

[image]

however my component is indeed a functional component...
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

[the package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive) you are using is only for react.js.

For React Native you can use

[React Native Responsive Screen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-screen)

example given in react-native-responsive-screen

```
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
 
class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.textWrapper}>
          <Text style={styles.myText}>Login</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1 },
  textWrapper: {
    height: hp('70%'), // 70% of height device screen
    width: wp('80%')   // 80% of width device screen
  },
  myText: {
    fontSize: hp('5%') // End result looks like the provided UI mockup
  }
});
 
export default Login;
```

Comment: Ah ok thx @Muhammad Iqbal but if i use react-native-web ?

Comment: @E.D I think this package will work on react-native-web too..

Comment: ok ! i will try but i need to change flexDirection too if mobile screen etc ....